# SBT fails to download Spark Streaming Kinesis library

Tags: sbt, spark-streaming, amazon-kinesis

I have the following on my `build.sbt` on a multi-project layout. All other dependencies resolve nicely and I just started on the Kinesis part of my project.

I have the following line in my build.sbt:

`libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kinesis-asl-assembly_2.10" % "2.0.0"`

and I get this error:

```
Error:Error while importing SBT project:
...
[error] 
[error]     spark-streaming-kinesis-asl: unable to get resource for org/codehaus/janino#janino;2.7.8: res=org.apache.spark/org/codehaus/janino/janino/2.7.8/janino-2.7.8.pom: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: org.apache.spark/org/codehaus/janino/janino/2.7.8/janino-2.7.8.pom
[error]     several problems occurred while resolving dependency: org.codehaus.janino#janino-parent;2.7.8 {}:
[error]     spark-streaming-kinesis-asl: unable to get resource for org/codehaus/janino#janino-parent;2.7.8: res=org.apache.spark/org/codehaus/janino/janino-parent/2.7.8/janino-parent-2.7.8.jar: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: org.apache.spark/org/codehaus/janino/janino-parent/2.7.8/janino-parent-2.7.8.jar
[error]     spark-streaming-kinesis-asl: unable to get resource for org/codehaus/janino#janino-parent;2.7.8: res=org.apache.spark/org/codehaus/janino/janino-parent/2.7.8/janino-parent-2.7.8.pom: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: org.apache.spark/org/codehaus/janino/janino-parent/2.7.8/janino-parent-2.7.8.pom
[error]     spark-streaming-kinesis-asl: unable to get resource for org/codehaus/janino#janino-parent;2.7.8: res=org.apache.spark/org/codehaus/janino/janino-parent/2.7.8/janino-parent-2.7.8.jar: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: org.apache.spark/org/codehaus/janino/janino-parent/2.7.8/janino-parent-2.7.8.jar
[error] 
[error] 
[error] unresolved dependency: com.google.http-client#google-http-client;1.19.0: several problems occurred while resolving dependency: com.google.http-client#google-http-client;1.19.0 {compile=[compile(*), master(*)], runtime=[runtime(*)]}:
[error]     several problems occurred while resolving dependency: com.google.http-client#google-http-client-parent;1.19.0 {}:
[error]     spark-streaming-kinesis-asl: unable to get resource for com/google/http-client#google-http-client-parent;1.19.0: res=org.apache.spark/com/google/http-client/google-http-client-parent/1.19.0/google-http-client-parent-1.19.0.jar: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: org.apache.spark/com/google/http-client/google-http-client-parent/1.19.0/google-http-client-parent-1.19.0.jar
[error]     spark-streaming-kinesis-asl: unable to get resource for com/google/http-client#google-http-client-parent;1.19.0: res=org.apache.spark/com/google/http-client/google-http-client-parent/1.19.0/google-http-client-parent-1.19.0.pom: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: org.apache.spark/com/google/http-client/google-http-client-parent/1.19.0/google-http-client-parent-1.19.0.pom
[error]     spark-streaming-kinesis-asl: unable to get resource for com/google/http-client#google-http-client-parent;1.19.0: res=org.apache.spark/com/google/http-client/google-http-client-parent/1.19.0/google-http-client-parent-1.19.0.jar: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: org.apache.spark/com/google/http-client/google-http-client-parent/1.19.0/google-http-client-parent-1.19.0.jar
[error] 
[error]     spark-streaming-kinesis-asl: unable to get resource for com/google/http-client#google-http-client;1.19.0: res=org.apache.spark/com/google/http-client/google-http-client/1.19.0/google-http-client-1.19.0.pom: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: org.apache.spark/com/google/http-client/google-http-client/1.19.0/google-http-client-1.19.0.pom
[error]     several problems occurred while resolving dependency: com.google.http-client#google-http-client-parent;1.19.0 {}:
[error]     spark-streaming-kinesis-asl: unable to get resource for com/google/http-client#google-http-client-parent;1.19.0: res=org.apache.spark/com/google/http-client/google-http-client-parent/1.19.0/google-http-client-parent-1.19.0.jar: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: org.apache.spark/com/google/http-client/google-http-client-parent/1.19.0/google-http-client-parent-1.19.0.jar
[error]     spark-streaming-kinesis-asl: unable to get resource for com/google/http-client#google-http-client-parent;1.19.0: res=org.apache.spark/com/google/http-client/google-http-client-parent/1.19.0/google-http-client-parent-1.19.0.pom: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: org.apache.spark/com/google/http-client/google-http-client-parent/1.19.0/google-http-client-parent-1.19.0.pom
[error]     spark-streaming-kinesis-asl: unable to get resource for com/google/http-client#google-http-client-parent;1.19.0: res=org.apache.spark/com/google/http-client/google-http-client-parent/1.19.0/google-http-client-parent-1.19.0.jar: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: org.apache.spark/com/google/http-client/google-http-client-parent/1.19.0/google-http-client-parent-1.19.0.jar
[error] Total time: 322 s, completed Dec 6, 2016 3:43:33 PM</pre><br/>See complete log in <a href="/Users/p2345716/Library/Logs/IntelliJIdea2016.3/sbt.last.log">/Users/p2345716/Library/Logs/IntelliJIdea2016.3/sbt.last.log</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by fixing the dependency artifactID:

`libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kinesis-asl-assembly" % "2.0.0"`